# group result by country and count

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have the following code;

```
$uid = '21';
$select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `profileuid` = ?");
$select->bindParam(1,$uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$select->execute();

foreach($select as $row){

    $country = $row['country'];
    echo  $country;
}
```

and the following database structure;

[image]

**Currently the above code gives this output**

```
United Kingdom
United Kingdom
United States
```

**My desired output**

```
United Kingdom 2
United States 1
```

Thanks for any help; I would attempt this myself but I don't know how to do a count like this. Could this possibly be a `GROUP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(1) as NoOfEntries  
FROM `reports` WHERE `profileuid` = ? 
GROUP BY Location
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

It will group the country and give the count.

Comment: Thankyou , Say I wanted to order by the NoOfEntries is that possible?

Comment: @Lewis, yes you can order using the NoOfEntries. Please check my updated answer